# How to add PDF-Viewer Tab to Channel in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Adding a PDF-Viewer tab to present/show a Sharepoint document has been working before.

I've tried this in January and it seemed to be an easy task - just get the DriveItem ID and URL (from GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}) and edit the sample from the API Reference with these values (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#word-excel-powerpoint-and-pdf-tabs).

Now, that i want to use this, it doesn't work anymore ;-( The tab is created, added to channel, the name of the file shows BUT there is no document!!! What am i missing? Has the format changed? Has someone lately gotten this to work???

Please let me know, how! ;-)

ps: there is no description of the property "entityID" that makes any sense, can anyone explain it?

[result in teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdEOp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, was a Syntax problem!

The "contentURL" property needs to be unescaped (in this case the "%20"). It is that simple after all ;-)

Also i found out, the "entityID" property has no meaning for the File used.  It can be "null" actually! I still use the ItemID i got from the DriveItem of the File.

For unescaping i used:

```
string contentUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(webUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't for this post I would have not gotten it figured out, so thank you!

For me I ended up having to make entityID null, just unescaping the contentURL didn't do it for me alone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. leaving entityID null fixed my isse also.
I opend an issue to have the docs fixed!